# How to remove string dtype from a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have an example data in the form of a *stringed* array in python,
Input: '[1,2,3,4,5]'

And I want to remove the quotes and convert the data into an array element,
Output: [1,2,3,4,5]

When I try int(), I get the following error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[1,2,3,4,5]'

Any help on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a neat function in python called `eval()` that you can use. This function basically evaluates a single python expression and runs it. So if you have `eval('print('Hello World!!')')` the eval functions will try to run the string as a python code.  For more info on `eval()` read [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_eval.asp) by w3schools.

For your problem, you can use a code like this:

```py
myArrString = '[1,2,3,4]'
myArrList = eval(myArrString)
```

Comment: @ManavMishra not really related to this specific question but if you are looking into using _eval()_ or _literal_eval()_ in the future,  go check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)
Long story short:
eval - can be dangerous if you read untrusted source.
literal_eval -is  considering only some syntax valid

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *ast* module

```
import ast
stringed = '[1,2,3,4,5]'
result = ast.literal_eval(stringed)
```